# C# Override abstract function with generic data

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstract

I'm trying to override an abstract function but I'm receiving an error when specifying a type for the list. The type has the interface that the base abstract class is requesting.

Base Renderer

```
public abstract class Renderer
{
    abstract void Render(Dictionary<GenericVAO, List<IEntity>> data);
}
```

Sprite Renderer

```
public class SpriteRenderer : Renderer
{
    public override void Render(Dictionary<GenericVAO, List<Sprite>> data) {}
}
```

Sprite

```
public class Sprite : IEntity
{
    public SpriteVAO model;
}
```

Comment: The type of the arguments is integral part of the Signature. And inheritances must match the Siganture. Either use a `List<IEntity>` or look at Overloading, not inheritance.

Comment: I cant make an overload for every type of renderer because the base renderer is suppose to be a outline of a renderer that the master renderer can deal with. I cant make overloads because new renderers are made outside of this library. Maybe I should change the base renderer to a interface? But I think ill still run into this issue

Comment: "Why `T<Base>` is not parent of `T<Derived>`" seem to be almost hourly question... I'd strongly recommend reading on that before you start coming up with "workarounds"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thats not my question at all. It wouldn't work even if the base and derived classes where swapped. Im asking how do I implement what I'm trying to do because my currently implementation is clearly incorrect.

Comment: IEntity exists, so you do not need to worry if you are given a Sprite, a Foo, or a Bar class. As long as they inherit from IEntity, they fit nicely in a `List<IEntity>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using generics for the renderer so that it just works for derived classes?
e.g.:

```
public abstract class Renderer<T> where T : IEntity
{
    abstract void Render(Dictionary<GenericVAO, List<T>> data);
}
```

Not sure if GenericVAO should be VAOof type T as well. Don't know exactly what you're doing.

Sprite renderer override then becomes:

```
public class SpriteRenderer : Renderer<Sprite>
{
    public override void Render(Dictionary<GenericVAO, List<Sprite>> data) {}
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Ive seen these generics before but never knew how they worked. Do you know any good reading on this subject?

Comment: Not off the top of my head sorry.  
The Microsoft documentation is always a good starting point that covers the basics (plus the links at the bottom of the page).  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/
I like Pluralsight for more in-depth learning, but I'm aware that it's not everyone's favourite choice, and it's also not free.